# Referring to an object of a derived class from the base class of another (unrelated!) class in C++

Tags: c++

If you can't understand the question title from the onset, it's not your fault - I couldn't think of a better description. Here is the explanation of the problem, which might be a bit lengthy, so apologies in advance.

In the initial version of my program, I had an Ecosystem class and an Individual class:

```
// Very simplified, for illustration purposes

class Ecosystem
{
    protected:
        // The int is just the ID of the individual.
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> > individuals;

    public:
        Ecosystem();
        void func(int _individual_id)
        {
            std::cout << "Individual's age: " 
                      << individuals[_individual_id]->get_age() 
                      << std::endl;
        }

        void routine(int _individual_id)
        {
            // Another function working via
            // the pointers in individuals.
        }        

        // More such functions...
};

class Individual
{
    protected:
        int age;

    public:
        Individual();
        inline int get_age() const
        {
            return age;
        }
};
```

The Ecosystem class contains dozens of functions, and I will add a lot more in the future.

I have now decided to split the Individual class into a base class and two derived classes, say TypeAIndividual and TypeBIndividual, because they each have members and attributes that the other one does not need (they also share a few members and attributes via the base class). So I have the base Individual class and two derived classes:

```
class TypeAIndividual : public Individual
{
    protected:
        // Data structures specific to individuals of type A

    public:
        TypeAIndividual();
};

class TypeBIndividual : public Individual
{
    protected:
        // Data structures specific to individuals of type B

    public:
        TypeBIndividual();
};
```

The problem is that the ecosystem now also needs to be split into TypeAEcosystem and TypeBEcosystem:

```
class Ecosystem
{
    protected:
        // Holding pointers to the base Individual class is pointless (pun not intended)
        // std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> > individuals;

    public:
        Ecosystem();
        // I want to keep func() in the base class
        // because it only accesses attributes and
        // members common to both classes derived
        // from Individual. 
        void func(int _individual_id)
        {
            // Hmmmm...
            // The pointers don't live in the Ecosystem class any more!
            std::cout << "Individual's age: " 
                      << individuals[_individual_id]->get_age() 
                      << std::endl; 
        }
        // OK to implement in each class
        // derived from Ecosystem.
        virtual void routine(int _individual_id) = 0;
};

class TypeAEcosystem : public Ecosystem
{    
    protected:
        // Pointers to individuals
        // of the corresponding type.
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TypeAIndividual> > individuals;

    public:
        TypeAEcosystem();
        // Reimplementing routine() is OK
        // because it does things specific to
        // this individual type.
        virtual void routine (int _individual_id)
        {
            // Operate on data structures particular
            // to this type of individual.
        }

};

class TypeBEcosystem : public Ecosystem
{
    protected:
        // Pointers to individuals
        // of the corresponding type.
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TypeBIndividual> > individuals;

    public:
        TypeBEcosystem();
        // Reimplementing routine() is OK
        // because it does things specific to
        // this individual type.
        virtual void routine (int _individual_id)
        {
            // Operate on data structures particular
            // to this type of individual.
        }
};
```

TypeAEcosystem and TypeBEcosystem both use `void func(int _individual_id)`, which needs to access individuals of the corresponding type. But the base class Ecosystem doesn't contain pointers to individuals any more because the `std::map`s are in each derived class and not in the base class.

My question is: how can I access the appropriate type of individual (`TypeAIndividual` or `TypeBIndividual`) while avoiding implementing separate `void func(int _individual_id)` in each class derived from Ecosystem? In other words, is there a way to keep `func()` in the base class so that when I change it, I don't have to make changes to the derived classes? In the actual program, there are dozens of functions like `func()` which take just an `int` as a parameter. Also, some of those functions take individual IDs from other structures in the `Ecosystem` class, so I can't simply pass a pointer to `TypeAIndividual` or `TypeBIndividual`.

### Things I have considered

- Merging `TypeAIndividual` and `TypeBIndividual` back into a common `Individual` class with all the data structures necessary for both derived classes. This strikes me as a particularly clumsy way of doing things, but at least it will work.
- Making `func()` & Co. virtual and implementing them in `TypeAEcosystem` and `TypeBEcosystem`. This means that if I want to make a change in any of the functions, I have to change both implementations (= a maintenance nightmare).
- Having only one `Ecosystem` class which holds `std::map`s of the two types of individuals, like this:

  ```
  // Seems clunky...
  class Ecosystem
  {
      protected:
          // Note: The Ecosystem can contain 
          // one OR the other, but not both!
          // One map will always be empty.
      std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TypeAIndividual> > type_a_individuals;

      std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TypeBIndividual> > type_b_individuals;

      public:
          Ecosystem();
          void func(int _individual_id)
          {
              // Check what type of individuals we 
              // are working with and operate on the
              // appropriate container.
              if (type_a_individuals.size() > 0)
              {
                  std::cout << "Individual's age: " 
                            << type_a_individuals[_individual_id]->get_age() 
                            << std::endl; 
              }
              else
              {
                  std::cout << "Individual's age: " 
                            << type_b_individuals[_individual_id]->get_age() 
                            << std::endl; 
              }
          }
  };
  ```

This would require inserting a check in every function, which is almost as bad in terms of maintainability as having the functions in separate classes.

**Note**: Although I would very much like to avoid passing pointers around, I would consider upcasting and/or downcasting as appropriate (as a last resort...) if it solves the problem.

Any suggestions are welcome!

---

**Edit 1**

Thank you all for the fantastic responses! As suggested by both amit and Chris, and looked at my `Ecosystem` class and sure enough, it was too bulky. I moved member functions around into other classes and now I'm down to four or five essential functions in the `Ecosystem` class. The `Ecosystem` class resides in a library and provides an interface for conducting experiments with individuals, but I don't want users to be able to manipulate `Individual`s and other classes directly, so I can't do away with it completely.

I liked all suggestions, there are some ingenious solutions. That being said, the one proposed by Chris grabbed my attention immediately for being very neat and allowing me to have a single Ecosystem class rather than three separate classes (base and two derived). The type of individual can be specified in a config file, and I can spawn multiple ecosystems from different config files within the same experiment. This is the accepted answer.

Thank you again everyone for the constructive input!

Comment: `The Ecosystem class contains dozens of functions, and I will add a lot more in the future.` sounds like a [god-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) to me. Consider refactoring it.

Comment: I maybe add a more elaborate answer in the evening as I have some work to do at the moment. 
However just by looking at it I came up with two possible solutions:

Make the Ecosystem a template class.
template <typename IndividualType>
class EcoSystem {
   std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<IndividualType> > individuals;
};

and get rid of different ecosystems.

Or store pointers to base class individuals in the base Ecosystem as you have already considered yourself.

Comment: Why not have only one `Ecosystem` class, and have a `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> >` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already said in my comment you could consider making Ecosystem a templated class and have one instance of an Ecosystem for each IndivualType.

```
template <class IndivualType>
class Ecosystem {
  protected:
    // The int is just the ID of the individual.
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<IndivualType> > individuals;
  public:
    // ...
};
```

In case you need the Ecosystem to behave different for a given IndividualType, you can in addition explicitly specialize your Ecosystem like so:

```
template <>
class Ecosystem<SpecialIndividualType> {
protected:
        // The int is just the ID of the individual.
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<SpecialIndividualType> > individuals;
      public:
        // special implementation for EcoSystem for SpecialIndividualType 
};
```

This probably will not be necessary, however it may be good to know.

Finally as you said the

```
The Ecosystem class contains dozens of functions, and I will add a lot more in the future.
```

You may want to consider to split the functionality of your ecosystem into policies. I dont know your needs but just as an example:

```
template <class IndivualType, class SomePolicy1, class SomePolicy2>
class Ecosystem {
  private:
    const SomePolicy1 mSp1;
    const SomePolicy2 mSp2;
  protected:
    // The int is just the ID of the individual.
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<IndivualType> > individuals;
  public:
    Ecosystem (const SomePolicy1& sp1= SomePolicy1(), const SomePolicy2& sp2= SomePolicy2())) : mSp1(sp1), mSp2(sp2) {}
    // ...
    void func(int _individual_id) 
        mSp1.doSmth(_individual_id);
    }

    void func2(int _individual_id) {
        mSp2.doSmth(_individual_id);
    }
};
```

This is called "policy based design", you can find a lot of information about it on the web.

Of course there are other solutions as well, such as making the methods virtual  as already mentioned. I would probably try both (depending on the time you have) and see what you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation details, I assume these. The eco system is a container/processor class of individuals. Looking at the interface the ids seems to be unique across different individuals, i.e. A invidual and B individual can not have same id. 
If these are true, I will stick to one ecosystem class which defines the interface to access individuals, which can be stored in a map (base pointers*) since the ids are unique. Then ofc you can use dynamic casting from outside if you want to know which type is being requested and other manipulations can be done using the polymorphic interface of the individual classes. I also highly recommend you to use the implementation suggested by Herb Sutter http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm#Notes because lot of experts highly acknowledge it for extendability among others.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a virtual method in `EcoSystem` to retrieve generic `TypeIndividual`:

```
class EcoSystem
{
public:

    void func(int _individual_id) {
        std::cout << "Individual's age: " 
                  << get_individual(_individual_id).get_age() 
                  << std::endl; 
        }

    virtual const TypeIndividual& get_individual(int _individual_id) const = 0;
    virtual void routine(int _individual_id) = 0;
};
```

And for each subclass:

```
class TypeAEcosystem : public Ecosystem
{
protected:
    // Pointers to individuals of the corresponding type.
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TypeAIndividual> > individuals;

public:
    const TypeIndividual& get_individual(int _individual_id) const override
    {
        return *individuals.at(_id);
    }


    // Reimplementing routine() is OK
    // because it does things specific to
    // this individual type.
    void routine (int _individual_id) override
    {
        // Operate on data structures particular
        // to this type of individual.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Both derived `Ecosystem`'s differ in their way to store and access the `Individual`'s. That's a good case for making the `Individual` access behaviour virtual. With a dash of return type covariance, it looks quite fine :

```
struct Individual                   { void baseStuff()  {} };
struct TypeAIndividual : Individual { void typeAStuff() {} };

struct Ecosystem {

    void func(int id) {
        individual(id).baseStuff();
    }

    virtual void routine(int id) = 0;

protected:
    virtual Individual &individual(int id) = 0;
};

struct TypeAEcosystem : Ecosystem {

    TypeAIndividual &individual(int id) override {
        return *_individuals.at(id);
    }

    void routine(int id) override {
        individual(id).typeAStuff();
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TypeAIndividual>> _individuals;
};
```

Since the map and its accessor(s) are identical except for the type of individual, you can factor them out into an intermediary template base class :

```
template <class Individual>
struct DerivedEcosystem : Ecosystem {

    Individual &individual(int id) override {
        return *_individuals.at(id);
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual>> _individuals;
};

struct TypeAEcosystem : DerivedEcosystem<TypeAIndividual> {

    void routine(int id) override {
        individual(id).typeAStuff();
    }
};
```