# Is it possible to pass a variable only once per class but not make it static?

Tags: c++

This question is (loosely) related to something I asked yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981694/referring-to-an-object-of-a-derived-class-from-the-base-class-of-another-unrela).

I have just refactored a container class (`Ecosystem`), which contains pointers to `Individual`s:

```
class Ecosystem
{
    // This is an interface class providing access
    // to functions in Individual without exposing
    // the Individual class.
    // It performs global operations on the entire ecosystem
    // (like sorting individuals based on certain criteria)
    // but is also capable of invoking functions from the
    // Individual class.
    // It also holds the global configuration for this ecosystem.
    private:
        Config config;
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> > individuals;
    public:
        Ecosystem() {};
        void sort_individuals();
        void func1(int _individual_id)
        {
            individuals[_individual_id]->func1(config);
        }

        void func2(int _individual_id)
        {
            individuals[_individual_id]->func2(config);
        }
        // etc...
};

class Individual
{
    private:

    public:
        Individual() {};
        void func1(const Config& _config)
        {
            // Operations using _config.param_1, _config.param_2, ... 
        }

        void func2(const Config& _config)
        {
            // Operations using _config.param_n, _config.param_m, ... 
        }
        // etc...
}
```

I am now in the situation where I have to pass `config` with practically every function call to `Individual` objects. Initially I thought, well, I'll just make a `static Config config;` inside `Individual`, but soon I realised that I need to be able to create multiple coexisting ecosystems with different configurations.

If I understand the implications of `static` correctly, if I have `static Config config;` inside `Individual` which is assigned the value of `config` from `Ecosystem`, it will get overwritten each time I create a new ecosystem.

My question is: is there a way to pass `config` **once** to the Individual class **without making it static** in order to avoid passing it as an argument with each function?

I have considered having `Config* config` in both `Ecosystem` and `Individual`, but this means that every individual will have a pointer to the config object, which seems clunky. What I need is the equivalent of a static member whose scope is aware of the container hierarchy, if that makes any sense.

Once created, a Config object will not be altered, so it's possible to have a `const Config config;`.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

---

**EDIT 1**

Thank you everyone for your responses. Matthew Kraus had a point that I didn't provide the right constructor of my Ecosystem class in the original question, which is, of course, an oversight on my side. I see now that it might have been relevant, but I was focusing more on illustrating what kind of variable access I'm after rather than what my classes look like, so I presented a simple example. Apologies if I brought in confusion to the discussion with my extra comments!

The solutions proposed here are all very good, but I can see from the answers that C++ doesn't have any means of defining such class-level variables without defining them as `static`. What I need is a class-level variable whose scope is limited to its container. This is just an illustration of my idea, it will not compile (and I am certain by now that this cannot be done in C++):

```
class Ecosystem
{
    // This is an interface class providing access
    // to functions in Individual without exposing
    // the Individual class.
    // It performs global operations on the entire ecosystem
    // (like sorting individuals based on certain criteria)
    // but is also capable of invoking functions from the
    // Individual class.
    // It also holds the global configuration for this ecosystem.

    private:

        Config config;
        std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> > individuals;

    public:
        Ecosystem(const std::string& _file_name)
        {
            Config cfg(_file_name);

            config = cfg;

            // This is done before any Individual objects are created.
            Individual::set_config(cfg);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
            {
                individuals[i] = std::make_shared<Individual>();
            }
        };

        void sort_individuals();

        void func1(int _individual_id)
        {
            individuals[_individual_id]->func1();
        }

        void func2(int _individual_id)
        {
            individuals[_individual_id]->func2();
        }
        // etc...
};

class Individual
{
    private:
        // v--- No such thing!
        scoped static Config config;

    public:
        Individual() {};

        void func1()
        {
            // Operations using config.param_1, config.param_2, ... 
        }

        void func2()
        {
            // Operations using config.param_n, config.param_m, ...
        }

        // v--- No such thing!
        scoped static void set_config(const Config& _config)
        {
            config = _config;
        }
        // etc...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Ecosystem ecosystem1("config_file1.txt");

    Ecosystem ecosystem2("config_file2.txt");

    // Conduct experiments with the two ecosytems.
    // Note that when ecosystem2 is created, the line
    //
    // Individual::set_config(cfg);
    //
    // should *not* overwrite the class-level variable
    // config set when ecosystem1 was created. 
    // Instead, it should create a
    // class-level variable but limited to the scope of ecosystem 2.

    // This operates on Individual 1 in ecosystem 1
    // with the parameters set in config_file1.txt
    ecosystem1->func1(1);

    // This operates on Individual 1 in ecosystem 2
    // with the parameters set in config_file2.txt
    ecosystem2->func1(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I will go with the suggestion to pass a pointer to the config to each individual at construction time. This will waste space but should be the most easily maintainable solution.

Again, thank you all for your input, and apologies if the question was confusing.

Comment: Assuming you can guarantee that the `Config` object will outlive all `Individual`s,  why not give `Individual` a `Config const&` member that's passed in the constructor?

Comment: @user657267 Because that breaks the assignment operator of `Individual`.

Comment: You'd have to write your own assignment operator that is implemented in terms of constructor, which should not be too much of a problem

Comment: @nwp It doesn't "break" the operator, it just makes the implicit assignment operator deleted. OP is free to define his own assignment operator if necessary. If reassigning `Config` is necessary he can always make it a pointer.

Comment: So it looks like you want one config per container, and you want all objects you place in a container to "inherit" this config. Is this correct?

Comment: @nwp see my answer below; this is why I prefer to use `explicit`.

Comment: @MatthewKraus What I meant is that you cannot move `Individual`s from one `Ecosystem` to another, because that requires assigning a new `Config`, which you cannot. `explicit` or implementations with a copy constructor don't help there.

Comment: @nwp You could use `std::map<int, Individual*> individuals;` in Ecosystem instead of std::shared_ptr, and remove the dependency on `Config` as I have in my example below. Then you can totally move `Individual`s between `Ecosystem`s because it's just a pointer copy, which won't invoke assignment operators or copy constructors.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, that is correct - one config per `Ecosystem` which is accessible by all individuals in that ecosystem, but not by individuals in other ecosystems.

Comment: @MatthewKraus Individuals will not be moved across ecosystems because they are actually templated, and different specialisations will be incompatible with each other in terms of operation (I should have mentioned that, sorry). That's why I need a config per Ecosystem which is accessible *only* to individuals in that ecosystem.

Comment: @nodialtone, that additional info changes everything! You can propagate the const reference to `Config` throughout your classes, or you could use dependency injection: instead of passing const `Config` references to `Individual::func1()`, you could do something like `Individual::func1(T1 configParam1, T2 configParam2, ...)`. This way, you remove the dependency of `Individual` on `Config`.

Comment: @nodialtone I feel like we've given you several answers to your question of _"is there a way to pass config once to the Individual class without making it static"._ At this point, we're starting to dive deeper into design issues, so it might make sense to **upvote some of the more useful comments and answers, and mark an accepted answer**.

Comment: I would say passing the config to each individual function isn't that terrible either. If you present your API as methods of Ecosystem that take an individual's ID, rather than methods of the Individual class. the clients need not worry about that.

Comment: If you can allow classes of `Individual` and `EcoSystem` with different `config`s to be classes, you can use `template` to make each of them have its own copy of static `config`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, passing a config to a constructor of an `Individual` should do:

```
class Individual {
    const Config& config_;
public:
    Individual(const Config& c) : config_(c) {}
    void func1() {
        // use config_
    }
};
```

You still have to pass `Config` to every individual constructor, but this is a single point, rather than however many functions `Individual` will have. Moreover, you could encapsulate the creation of an `Individual` into a factory method if you felt like the creation was too cumbersome.

Comment: I did think along these lines (albeit with a pointer to a Config object), but I was trying to avoid having a pointer/reference to the config in *each* individual. Also, individuals are created by a number of functions, and I was hoping to get away with a single config assignment **per ecosystem**.

Comment: Why are you concerned about having a reference in each individual? Is it a space concern?

Comment: And in terms of creation, would it be acceptable to force users to create Individuals always through a uniform interface presented by an `Environment`?

Comment: Yes, I was concerned about wasting space because I might have millions of individuals within an ecosystem, so I'm trying to minimise the number of variables that each individual carries around. However, this seems like the most maintainable solution, so I have marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If `Individual` objects shouldn't contain a configuration, then there is always

```
class ConfiguredIndividualReference
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Individal> ptr; // or just Individual* depending on how you use this
    const Config &config;
public:
    // ...
    void func1()
    {
        ptr->func1(config);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Furthermore, you can make a member function to automatically generate this:

```
ConfiguredIndividualReference fetch(int id) const {
    return ConfiguredIndividualReference(individuals[id], config);
}
```

and always use this to fetch the individuals rather than directly accessing the map.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but this makes it possible to have more than one `Config` associated with an `Individual`. Maybe this is desired, but if there should only be a 1:1 correspondence, you might be able to make a hash table for `Individual` that maps to a single `Config`. My preference would be to be explicit about what is allowed; if you want to allow 1:n, then make a data structure that explicitly supports that. My intuition tells me that it would be all too easy to have multiple `ConfiguredIndividualReference`s lying around. Nevertheless, it looks like a work-around to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few answers trickled in while I was working on a solution, but I thought I'd post my answer anyway. Here is a complete solution to see everything in context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Config
{
public:
    explicit Config(std::string name) : name(name) {}

    std::string getName() const { return name; }

private:
    std::string name;
};

class Individual
{
public:
    // using 'explicit' ensures that an Individual is created with a Config
    explicit Individual(const Config& config) :
        config(config) {}

    std::string getConfigName() const { return config.getName(); }

    void func1() {}
    void func2() {}

private:
    // a "const reference" is read-only
    const Config& config;
};

// notice that the dependency on Config is removed from Ecosystem
class Ecosystem
{
    private:
        // std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> > individuals;
        // I compiled using Individual*, so be aware
        // of the implications of using a naked ptr vs shared_ptr
        std::map<int, Individual*> individuals

    public:
        Ecosystem() {};

        void sort_individuals();
        void func1(int _individual_id)
        {
            // no dependency on Config
            individuals[_individual_id]->func1();
        }

        void func2(int _individual_id)
        {
            individuals[_individual_id]->func2();
        }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Config globalConfig("global configuration");
    Config localConfig("local configuration");

    // the Config object passed to an Individual must
    // last the lifetime of the Individual
    Individual individualA(globalConfig);
    Individual individualB(localConfig);

    // the following prints "global configuration"
    cout << "individualA config is: " << individualA.getConfigName() << endl;

    // the following prints "local configuration"
    cout << "individualB config is: " << individualB.getConfigName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As noted in the code, be sure that the `Config` object out-lives any object that depends on it. Sharing object like this--even if you are making a const reference--removes the physical dependency, but it doesn't remove the logical dependency. In other words, the C++ compiler can compile the `Ecosystem` class without knowledge of a `Config`. However, the `Ecosystem` depends on `Individual`s, which in turn depend on `Config`s, so be forewarned. My point here is that a const reference is the vanilla C++ way to do this, but it might be worth considering `std::shared_ptr` if managing the lifetime of `Config` objects is anything but trivial.

**Edit**

I didn't actually use `shared_ptr` when I compiled this; I used `Individual*` in the map. Just be aware of the implications of using one vs. the other.

Comment: The problem is that users can't create `Individual` or `Config` objects in main(). They only have access to the Ecosystem, which is the only entry point (interface) to the library, so they have to create an Ecosystem object, which takes a config file name (std::string) as a parameter.

Comment: @nodialtone I didn't see a `Ecosystem(std::string)` constructor in your original post. Your comment implies that one exists. I (and others here) were giving you the best answers we could based on your original code. Changing the story as answers roll in makes it difficult to provide you with a good solution. I think we could have served you better if you had fully loaded us with more context, but I hope we've helped you figure out a solution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a second answer to meet the new requirement of only having one `Config` per `Ecosystem` instead of one per `Individual`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Config
{
public:
    explicit Config(std::string name) : name(name) {}

    std::string getName() const { return name; }

private:
    std::string name;
};

class Individual
{
public:
    Individual() {}

    void func1(const Config& config) const
    {
        std::cout << config.getName() << std::endl;
    }

    // you might remove the dependency of Config and
    // just pass only the config parameters needed.
    void func2(Type1 configParam1, Type2 configParam2) {}
};

// notice that the dependency on Config is removed from Ecosystem
class Ecosystem
{
public:
    explicit Ecosystem(Config& config) : config(config) {}

    void sort_individuals();
    void func1(int _individual_id)
    {
        individuals[_individual_id]->func1(config);
    }

private:
    // std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Individual> > individuals;

    // I compiled using Individual*, so be aware
    // of the implications of using a naked ptr vs shared_ptr
    std::map<int, Individual*> individuals;

    const Config& config;    
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Config globalConfig("global configuration");

    // Config objects don't need to be created in main();
    // you could create them on the heap, too:
    Config* localConfig = new Config("local configuration");

    Ecosystem ecosystemA(globalConfig);
    Ecosystem ecosystemB(*localConfig);

    // TODO: add Individuals to each Ecosystem

    // clean up objects on heap
    delete localConfig;

    return 0;
}
```

I feel like we already answered the OP's original question of *"is there a way to pass config once to the Individual class without making it static in order to avoid passing it as an argument with each function"*. This example gives a few more options.

The addition here is creating the `Config` object on the heap. This makes the caller of `Ecosystem(Config& config)` responsible for managing the `Config` object. Again, this doesn't have to happen in `main()`, but you might modify my example to use smart pointers to automatically manage the lifetime of `Config` objects.